# Send webdriver/eclipse project via a link

Tags: eclipse, github, webdriver

I have developed a webdriver automation script on eclipse. I need to share the project as a whole with someone. How do I send it as a link via github repo or via a zip file (github preferred) without any data being lost?

Answer (score 0):

You can push your code to GitHub and add the consumer to the GitHub repo under settings->collaborators. He should be able to view the repository once you do that.

Comment: Can you please guide me further. I am new to GITHub. How do I do this?

Comment: Make sure you have your git setup locally and create a repository in GitHub.Pull the repository on to your project and push your project to GitHub.Once you do that , you should be able to see your files in the GitHub, Navigate to Settings-> Collaborators and add the person to whom you would like to share your code.